# Is a continuous function defined on a closed interval always riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, riemann-integration

Is a continuous function defined on a closed interval on $R$ always Riemann integrable or are there counter examples?

I'm thinking it is true because it sounds like it would always be possible to find step functions to bound it?

Comment: Closed, *bounded* interval, yes.  Reason: uniform continuity.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Yes.  But I don't believe that the OP was talking about the extended real line; for $\mathbb{R}$, closed implies bounded.

Comment: @Dr.MV you're probably right, but it never hurts to be precise.  The function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is continuous on the closed interval $[1,\infty)$ (as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, not the extended real line), but isn't integrable.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Yes, redundancy, repeating, and stating the same thing over and over is fine, acceptable, and all right.  ;-))

Comment: @Dr.MV The other reason I mentioned boundedness is that it's necessary to conclude uniform continuity from ordinary continuity.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I up voted your comment as useful because of its content including the UC connection.  I was only remarking that the boundedness part is superfluous given closedness.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/890953/riemann-integrability-of-continuous-function-defined-on-closed-interval?rq=1) asks to verify a (correct) proof of this statement.  Possible duplicate?